# moderntimeline incompatibility with positioning using Beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning

I am preparing a slide for my PhD defense with a list of research stays with some tasks and publications. If I create the timeline by itself, there is no problem. But when integrating it with my presentation since I need \usetikzlibrary{positioning} for some parts of my code, then the labels of the timeline get missplaced. Compare the two images below.

Here is a code sample.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%%%%% --- Stuff needed for the modern timeline in Beamer
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[firstyear=2009,lastyear=2014]{moderntimeline}

\makeatletter
% change these colors according to your needs
\colorlet{color0}{blue}
\colorlet{color1}{olive}

\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{a~}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries\raggedright #3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, \raggedright{\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{,  \raggedright#5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, \raggedright#6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small\raggedright#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} & {#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
\tlmaxdates{2009}{2014}
\newlength{\quotewidth}
\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\newlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
\newlength{\maincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\doubleitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listitemsymbolwidth}
\settowidth{\listitemsymbolwidth}{\listitemsymbol}
\newlength{\listitemmaincolumnwidth}
\newlength{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}
\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\dimexpr0.9\linewidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth\relax}

\tikzset{
    tl@startyear/.append style={
        xshift=(0.5-\tl@startfraction)*\hintscolumnwidth,
        anchor=base
    }
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%% ----- Packages necessary for the rest of the slides
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\tldatelabelcventry{2009.580}{June 2009}{MSc Thesis}{}{}
{}{}{}

\tllabelcventry{2009.583}{2009.833}{July-Sept. 2009}{Research stay}{Some Lab at SomeUniversity}
{Somewhere}{}{
\vspace{-10pt}
\begin{itemize}\setlength\itemsep{-5pt}
\item[--] task 1
\item task 2
\item More awesome tasks we developed
\end{itemize}
}

\tllabelcventry{2011.500}{2011.995}{June-Dec. 2011}{Research stay}{Some Lab at SomeUniversity}{Seomewhere}{}{}

\tldatelabelcventry{2010.500}{June 2010}{Some Conf. 2010}{}{}
{}{Some A, some title some year}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

That is the expected (this is generated by commenting `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` ):
[image]

And that is what is obtained with the provided code:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that `positioning` redefines the `above` key which is used by `moderntimeline` to position the text over the timeline.

Here are two patches that could solve your problem.

One is to redefine the macro `\tl@textstartabove` using `\def` and not using `\pgfmathsetmacro` as is done in `moderntimeline.sty`:

```
\def\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width+1pt}
```

My guess is that `\pgfmathsetmacro` interferes with the more complicated argument parsing that the `positioning` `above` is doing but the actual reason is beyond my knowledge.

Since the patched command works with *and* without `positioning` it could be applied to the `moderntimeline` package by changing the definition of `\tlwidth` at line 34:

```
\newcommand{\tlwidth}[1]{%
   \def\tl@width{#1}
   \def\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width+1pt}
}
```

---

Another patch is setting an explicit value for `y` in the frame with the timelines, thus affecting the vertical space between the timelines and the labels.